# plt.boxplot showing up blank despite thousands of varying datapoints

Tags: python, matplotlib, boxplot

I have a numpy 1D array of around 7000 in length. 
Here is a snippet: 
.2
1.2
1.2
1.2
1.2
1.2
1.2
1.2
1.2
1.2
1.2
1.2
1.2
1.2
1.2
1.2
1.2
1.2
1.2
1.2
1.2
1.2
0.8
0.8
0.8
0.8
0.8
0.8
0.8
0.8
0.8
0.8
0.8
0.8
0.8
0.8
0.8
0.8
0.8
0.8
0.8
0.8
0.8
0.8
0.8
0.8
0.8
0.8
0.8
1.4
1.4
1.4
1.4
1.4
1.4
1.4
1.4
1.4
1.4
1.4
1.4
1.4
1.4
1.4
1.4
1.4
1.4
1.4
1.4
1.4
1.4
1.4
1.4
1.4
1.4
1.4
1.4
1.4
1.4
1.4
1.4
1.4
1.4
1.4
1.4
1.4
1.4
1.4
1.4
1.4
1.4
1.4
1.4
1.4
1.4
1.4
1.4
1.9
1.9
1.9
1.9
1.9
1.9
1.9
1.9
1.9
1.9
1.9
1.9
1.9

When I graph the boxplot it comes up blank. When I change it to a pandas DF it graphs appropriately, however for the rest of my code to work I need to graph it with either pylab or pyplot.

Here is my code:

`plt.figure(1)
plt.boxplot(array)
plt.savefig('test.png')`

Here is what it looks like:
[image]

If i plot it using plt.plot(array) 
I get: 
[image]

Thank you

Comment: Please make an [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), i.e. give an actual array in the code which produces this output.

Answer (score 8):

I had the same error. The first step is to check if you have any NaN values. A quick way to do that is to run:

```
import numpy as np
if np.isnan(your_array).any():
  print("There are NaN values, I need to remove")
```

Once you have checked for NaN values, you might find that you still see the blank plot. I found that a way to go around this was to plot directly onto the axis. You can do that using:

```
fig1, ax1 = plt.subplots()
ax1.set_title('Basic Plot')
ax1.boxplot(your_array)
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 4):

I had the same issue, which was caused by Nans in the data. Check if you have removed all the null values.

Answer (score 1):

The following code

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

array = np.array([.2, 1.2, 1.2, 1.2, 1.2, 1.2, 1.2, 1.2, 1.2, 1.2, 1.2, 1.2, 1.2, 1.2, 1.2, 1.2, 1.2, 1.2, 1.2, 1.2, 1.2, 1.2, 0.8, 0.8, 0.8, 0.8, 0.8, 0.8, 0.8, 0.8, 0.8, 0.8, 0.8, 0.8, 0.8, 0.8, 0.8, 0.8, 0.8, 0.8, 0.8, 0.8, 0.8, 0.8, 0.8, 0.8, 0.8, 0.8, 0.8, 1.4, 1.4, 1.4, 1.4, 1.4, 1.4, 1.4, 1.4, 1.4, 1.4, 1.4, 1.4, 1.4, 1.4, 1.4, 1.4, 1.4, 1.4, 1.4, 1.4, 1.4, 1.4, 1.4, 1.4, 1.4, 1.4, 1.4, 1.4, 1.4, 1.4, 1.4, 1.4, 1.4, 1.4, 1.4, 1.4, 1.4, 1.4, 1.4, 1.4, 1.4, 1.4, 1.4, 1.4, 1.4, 1.4, 1.4, 1.4, 1.9, 1.9, 1.9, 1.9, 1.9, 1.9, 1.9, 1.9, 1.9, 1.9, 1.9, 1.9, 1.9])

plt.figure(1)
plt.boxplot(array)
plt.show()
```

produces this image:

[image]

Comment: Yes the rest of mine work lik that but this does not. I am trying to see if anyone else has exprienced the same issue. To ensure my array was correct I exported to to a txt file directly before the boxplot is executed. It is as above... but the bp is still not showing up